I'm getting an error when running tests with jest and remix
I'm getting an error when running tests with jest and remix
I'm trying to set up a project using remix and I took the test I saw in the doc as an example to test in the project and I'm getting an error.
This is my first question on stackoverflow after 10 years of using it, I don't even know what to search for anymore. I've done all the suggested configurations and nothing.
Repository link: https://github.com/carvalhothiago/teste-jest
The test file is the one in the doc: https://remix.run/docs/en/main/other-api/testing
To run it, use npm i and then npm test
` FAIL  app/teste.test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

C:\Users\thiago\documentos\workspace\pessoal\teste-jest\node_modules\@web3-storage\multipart-parser\esm\src\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import {
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

> 1 | import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
    | ^
  2 | import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
  3 | import { createRemixStub } from "@remix-run/testing";
  4 | import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/teste.test.tsx:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.084 s
Ran all test suites.`
I tried to create a test project just to run a test with jest that was in the example in the remix doc
